# Prove: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-\ln(n)}{n^x}$, $x\in(1,\infty)$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

> Prove: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-\ln(n)}{n^x}$, $x\in(1,\infty)$
>   converges uniformly

**My attempt:**

For every $x>2$

$$\left|\frac{-\ln(n)}{n^x}\right|=\frac{\ln(n)}{n^x}\le\frac{n}{n^x}=\frac{1}{n^{x-1}}\le \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}.$$

Therefore converges uniformly by the M-test.
But I'm having trubles proving for $1<x<2$

Comment: The RHS of your inequality should be one over $n$ to the power $1+\epsilon$.

Comment: You can't use a weak inequality like $\ln(n) \leq n$ for $x\in (1,2)$. Use that for any $\delta > 0$ we have $\ln(n) < n^{\delta}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Your choice of $\epsilon$ depends on $x$, so your proof for $x>2$ is not valid.

Comment: The series does not converge uniformly on $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: @T.Bongers then how come $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x})'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-ln(n)}{n^x}$?

Comment: @Ro168 Because the sum on the right converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$ for each $a>1.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If each $f_n$ is bounded on a set $E$ and $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E,$ then $f$ is bounded on $E.$ In your problem, each summand is bounded on $(1,\infty).$ Is the sum bounded on $(1,\infty)?$